# Desktop doesn't boot

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure

So I think I stuck a chunk of incompatible RAM on my mobo, smelled a burning smell and after switching out the RAM my machine wouldn't boot. Assumed mobo was fried and got a new one.

I also recently got a stronger PSU.

Fitting them all back together and on start up the fans whir briefly before coming to a stop. No warning/check beeps from the mobo, but the green status light is on when the power is running. Maybe I need to install some firmware somehow to properly install the mobo?

Disconnected my GFX card, wifi adapter and SSD drives. Still same result.

At this stage the only things I haven't replaced are the CPU and the previously working RAM. How likely is it that this is the problem or some short somewhere on the remaining wiring or something else I haven't thought about?

Update: RAM is 2gb ddr3 from Crucial memory and new mobo is Asus P8Z68-V LX

Also the machine doesn't stay booted long enough for me to open the DVD tray.

Comment: More information on the motherboard(s) and the memory is required to help.

Comment: What about booting a ubuntu live-cd, if that doesn't boot up you can discard that it has to do with corrupted files. Then the only remaining possibilities are the ones you say, CPU or the working RAM

Comment: Took out the ram, still no sound so they said power. Checked the cabling again and one wasn't connected properly to mobo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all what happened, when you turn on your PC, the computer briefly starts, then stops, nothing happens but green light on motherboard is on? Sounds like power is not coming through. Try taking out RAM and boot up, if it's RAM fault, it should give you beeping errors; if it's same with RAM out, unplug and replug all connectors from PSU. Also, just for the hell of it, if you have a spare one, try changing power cable. I've had a few problems with faulty cables in the past.